# vb.net loop through datarow and add each value into a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, loops, datarow

```
Private Function ColumnEqual(ByVal A As Object, ByVal B As Object) As Boolean
  If A Is DBNull.Value AndAlso B Is DBNull.Value Then
    Return True 
  End If

  If A Is DBNull.Value OrElse B Is DBNull.Value Then
    Return False 
  End If

  Return A.Equals(B)
End Function
...

Public lastV As Object
...
For Each dr In wData.Rows
  If lastV Is Nothing OrElse Not ColumnEqual(lastV, dr("table1")) Then
    ''check if first value is nothing
    If lastV = Nothing Then
      lastV = "00"
      l = "0"
    Else
      dr("t1") = lastV
      dr("n1") = l
    End If
    ListBox1.Items.Add(lastV & " <--> " & l)
    lastV = dr("table1")
    l = 1
  ElseIf lastV Is Nothing OrElse ColumnEqual(lastV, dr("table1")) Then
    l += 1
  End If
Next
```

I use this code to loop through my `DataRow`.

It adds each record into a `ListBox`, but it does not add the last record in the
`DataRow` to the list.

Any help?

Comment: What is lastV and where do you have initialized these variables and this loop?

Comment: the loop is initialized when data is being loaded into the datagridview.

Comment: Sorry,   I  can't  make  head  or  tail  of  it.
But i strongly recommend to set "Option Strict" On in your Project Settings or - better- globally in your Visual Studio Options.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add each column in the datarow as a new ListBox item in your ListBox.

If I'm right, then the following example would do it. I'd use a DataSet:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
For j As Integer = 0 To wData.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
    ListBox1.Items.Add(wData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString)
    ListBox1.EndUpdate

    If j = wData.Tables(0).Column.Count - 1 Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

This will add the contents of each column in row i to the ListBox. The `If` statement stops it from incrementing `i` until it's added the last column.

Please bear in mind I haven't tested this code.

HTH